# Accessing multiple responses in SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I just learned soap a month ago and managed to get a reply in PHP. I managed to get a response and parse it but I am stuck with a different response where I get 5 instead of 1. Trying to figure out how to parse it. I'm so used to arrays and all that it's a bit confusing for me

Here is a normal response/reply

$value = $client->GetInmate($parameters);

```
        $xml = $value->GetInmateResult;

        print "Street: ".$xml->Address->Street;
        print "<br>City: ".$xml->Address->City;
        print "<br>State ".$xml->Address->State;
```

This works

Now I am trying to do something similar but my same method is not working, here is an image of the structure of the next reply:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWFxg.png

As you can see, I'm trying to get the 'Charges (5)' and manage them independently but racking my brain to do so. simplexml_load_string() isn't helping either, doesn't seem to parse them correctly.

Comment: Aren't you able to retrieve the result in the loop because it is the same format which i can see in the image attached. If not, then let me know the response which you are getting through this line:  $xml = $value->GetInmateResult;

Comment: A loop worked, I didn't think it would but thank you Aparna!!

Comment: My pleasure. You can upvote my comment. :)

Comment: Trying to but I think I need more rep for that? I can't see any vote buttons :(

Comment: Now u can do that, I have added that comment in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you able to retrieve the result in the loop because it is the same format which i can see in the image attached. If not, then let me know the response which you are getting through this line: 
$xml = $value->GetInmateResult